# Assigning a variable using optional chaining?

Tags: javascript, html

I know that only a few browsers support it as of this writing, but is there a clever way to assign a value to a key in a deeply nested object via optional chaining? I tried something like below, but it didn't work for me:

```
const foo = {bar: {baz: {quux: ''}}};
foo?.bar?.baz?.quux = 'quux'  // Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

The only way I could think of would just be to do a conditional check for it via:

```
if (foo?.bar?.baz?.quux)
  foo.bar.baz.quux = 'quux'
```

Is there perhaps a better way to do this?

Comment: Optional chaining [_"permits reading the value of a property located deep within a chain of connected objects"_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining). But it cannot be used for property assignment. Libraries can help you do it in a clean way, like [Lodash's `_.set()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#set) method. But otherwise, you will need to check/create the intermediate Objects yourself

Comment: Assignments have to go on left-hand side as your first example shows, and since you probably want to conditionally set the value, you can use `lodash.set`like this:

`foo?.bar?.baz?.quux && set(foo, 'bar.baz.quux', 'quux');`

Answer (score 0):

Some code such as some code in Google would do something like:

```js
const foo = {bar: {baz: {quux: ''}}};

foo && foo.bar && foo.bar.baz && (foo.bar.baz.quux = 'quux');
console.log(foo);

console.log(foo && foo.bar && foo.bar.wahla && foo.bar.wahla.haha);
```

but it'd be problematic if `foo.bar` is a truthy value and not an object.

Comment: The point of optional chaining was to avoid doing checks via `foo && foo.bar && foo.bar.baz && ...` I just wanted to see if there was a practical way to do it using optional chaining.