# Is there a proposal for optional chaining usable with setting properties

Tags: javascript, optional-chaining

[Assigning a variable using optional chaining?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60583388/assigning-a-variable-using-optional-chaining) asked the question about setting properties in a manner similar to [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), e.g., `foo?.bar?.baz?.quux = 'quux'` .

I'd like to ask more specifically if there is a proposal in the works to implement this (I didn't see one at https://github.com/tc39/proposals ), and if not, whether this was due to the original proposal rejecting the idea out of hand for some reason or another.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58878948/optional-chaining-on-the-left-side-in-javascript

Comment: Check out [this proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining).

Comment: Discussion about this can be found [here](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining/issues/18) - Daniel Ehrenberg says "We also discussed this question at TC39, and the committee did not seem so interested in adding this feature."

Comment: Thanks, I somehow missed that issue and that other question. I've voted to close the issue as a dupe---not sure if it is better etiquette to delete it? My question is a little more explicit in asking for that which may be helpful but the answer is there...

Comment: Nevermind, I hadn't seen the question to me. Should know better, but I guess this hasn't come up before, or if it did, I forgot. :-)

Comment: @BrettZamir yeah, don't delete this question even though its a duplicate. It can serve as a "sign-post" which future readers might stumble upon when searching a similar question.